# API to obtain the content of classic sharepoint sites

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api

The Microsoft graph API returns a 404 when trying to fetch the pages of a classic sharepoint site. What is the recommended API to fetch the pages of classic sharepoint sites?

Comment: Have you tried the old SharePoint REST API? For onprem you can use like, "http://myowndomain.com/_api/[site|web|search|...]/[lists|siteusers|...]/..." and for SPO you can use "https://myowndomain.sharepoint.com/_api/[site|web|search|...]/[lists|siteusers|...]/..."

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Do you happen to know where the documentation for this api is?

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have it handy. But let me see if i can get them.